# Problem in Ruby Shoes packaging?

Tags: windows, ruby, packaging, shoes

The (Ruby Shoes) packaging solution from Hacketyhack.net doesnt work.
Can anyone point me to an alternative?

Comment: Uhm... what? I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: It's a Ruby Shoes - it's a GUI frameowrk for Ruby.

Comment: I know its Ruby Shoes! do you guys have any idea about shoes? It has an option to package our project for Windows, Mac and Linux.. but it is not working on my machine... so i tried to look into it...and found out one pack.rb file ...where i suppose packaging is happening...and in the code some resource is taken from the hacketyhack.org site, which is not working!(_why is not there). so i was asking for some other pack.rb which will work!

Comment: @Aistina- if you dont want to help... its fine... but atleast don't disappoint others. sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [shoes/shoes github](http://github.com/shoes/shoes/downloads) project that hosts the latest binaries.  However, as of (Sept 10, 2009) packaging requires a few patches that remove the dependencies on _why's no longer existent server.

I was able to find pack.rb in the Shoes application folder and replace it with [this version of pack.rb](http://github.com/devyn/shoes/blob/689480d383b4de6a7a758681d0a70c239471d89c/lib/shoes/pack.rb) After that, my packager was able to package basic applications.

Comment: Hey it worked flawlessly! thanks. Do you know how can i give diff icon to my generated EXE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426965/how-do-i-change-the-icon-of-my-shoes-app/730071#730071 works to change the icon. The tool will let you edit icons embedded in the exe's resources. A tip I discovered was to "replace" the icon. Don't delete it and add a new.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful! (couldn't raise the vote again)

Answer (score 0):

There's a small tutorial in this [Juixe Techknow blog post](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2007/08/27/running-with-shoes-a-mini-gui/).  It provides a good introduction to Ruby Shoes.

Comment: thanks for this Shoes tutorial, but i know shoes, pretty well, i just want to package it for windows!..do you have any pointer for that